# Unable to clone git repository [Error in pull function]

Tags: 16.10, git, clone, github, katoolin

I'm trying to install kali linux tools using a script called Katoolin. But everytime I try to clone the repository, it displays the following error:

```
prabal@prabal-desktop:~$ git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git  && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
Cloning into 'katoolin'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

Its not in this case only but earlier also, when i was trying to install nmap or metasploit or any tool that required connecting to a https address through this command. I've no clue about what is going wrong.How to fix this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server/firewall/captive portal?

Comment: As far as I know.. I dont think so. But to be sure,   can you tell me a way to check whether i'm behind a firewall/captive portal ?

Comment: What does `curl -LI https://github.com` return?

Comment: @muru  Its giving this error - `prabal@prabal-desktop:~$ curl -LI https://github.com`
`curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300177 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received`

Comment: Here's the screenshot-
http://i.imgur.com/DN7vSBH.png